# Realistic page turn speed

Tags: javascript, math, animation, trigonometry

I have written some page turning software simulating a magazine.  Currently the speed of the page turning is linear, and I want to make it more realistic with acceleration and deceleration.

At the start of the animation it should be slow, half way through it should have reached max speed, then it returns to a slow speed by the end of the animation.

Someone I knew told me it can be done if you know what percentage of the animation you are through, using sine or something similar!

So given a percentage representing how far through the animation you are, how can you set the speed?

Answers in pseduo or javascript welcome :)

```
function speed(percentageThroughAnimation)
{
    return ?????
}
```

Comment: does this formula work? `maxspeed * animPercent * sin(animPercent * pi / 100) / 100`

Comment: @Nick D: when animpercent = 0 then speed = 0... That sounds like a bit too slow a start to me... Actually, it occurs to me that I'm assuming percentageThroughAnimation is in terms of position but if its time then I guess that works. Sorry. :)

Comment: @Chris, indeed I assume we start and stop with zero speed. If that causes problem in the animation we can add `+ minspeed` in the formula.

Comment: @Nick D: I edited my comment but to expand on my misundertanding I was thinking that animpercent was in terms of position. So if speed was zero then position would never change so speed would never change so you are stuck at the beginning. If animpercent is a function of time then it will work but thinking about it if you have a known time range you're better off with a position function than a speed one I'd have thought... Otherwise you run the risk of not making it to the end in time or too soon if your speed function is not quite right....

Comment: @Tom Gullen: What are you doing with this speed out of interest? Would you be better off with position as a function of time rather than speed as a function of something? And to clarify my confusion how is percentageThroughAnimation calculated? Is it in terms of time through or in terms of how far the page has been moved?

Comment: @Chris, I think speed has to do with the delay between frames, and assuming that animation percent isn't related to speed, there is no way to get _stuck_ :)

Comment: Speed is how many pixels the page 'moves'.  I know the start and end position of the movement, so it's easy to work out how far through the animation you are as a %.  The % is based on position and not a time reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's speed could be represented as a sinusoid function since pages are turning at an arc (more or less) and the page edge could be seen going at that speed.  Could use a sine of the position of the page edge.  That might work nice.

[edit]

javascript really isn't my forte but something like this maybe?

```
function speed(percentageThroughAnimation)
{
    //assuming percentage as indicator of page edge
    var pos = percentageThroughAnimation;

    //the (relative) speed is the sine of the position
    return Math.sin(Math.PI * pos);
}
```

Oops, corrected.  Double oops.  Should be in range [0, pi].

Comment: This is what I'm after, and basically understand how it works, but do you have a small formula how to achieve this in Javascript?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's nearly there but it gives out negative values and some other problems but I +1 you anyway :)